# Update a series of variable in SetState() efficiently (Dart-Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't find a simple way to update a series of variables in my Flutter project.
I first tried using Enums and functions to change the variables inside a `setState((){})` call.
I have something like this:

```
  void changeMode(Mode mode) {
if (mode == Mode.start) {
  print('App is now in start mode');
  mode = Mode.start;
  bool1 = true;
  bool2 = false;
  bool3 = false;
  color1 = kAColor1;
  color2 = kAColor2;
} else if ...}
```

But nothing gets updated, I imagine it's due the fact that my function doesn't return anything.

If I hard code every single variable in `setState((){})` it works fine, but it's absolutely inefficient and a mess to correct.

Maybe I should go with classes? Would I need to create a superclass containing all the subclasses to do something like this?

Comment: Have you tried to print values you was passing to these variables?

Comment: The initial print statement gets executed but variables don't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time that you call setState you UI will rebuild. You can use `class` or `map` to manipulate your data.

**With class:**

```dart
setState(() {
  currentData = actualData.copyWith(bool1: false)
})
```

This way, you change only data that is different from `currentData`. On this example, I maintain all information from `currentData` and change only `bool1` value.

> Obs: `copyWith` is a `factory` that return the same type of
> `currentData`.